# Android parse push notification not working in some devices

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hello I am working with parse push notification for android.I developed app using the following  tutorial. http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/. I can able to get the notification onl in one device which is lollipop.I didin't get notification in kitkat and other devices. I didin't find the issue.

here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android_new_user.testnotification" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.android_new_user.testnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.android_new_user.testnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android_new_user.testnotification.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android_new_user.testnotification.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".CustomPushReciver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my reciver File is looks like

```
package com.example.android_new_user.testnotification;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
/**
 * Created by Android_new_user on 11/25/2015.
 */
public class CustomPushReciver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    private final String TAG = CustomPushReciver.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    private Intent parseIntent;

    public CustomPushReciver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushReceive(context, intent);

        if (intent == null)
            return;

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

            Log.e(TAG, "Push received: " + json);

            parseIntent = intent;

            parsePushJson(context, json);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Push message json exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushDismiss(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushDismiss(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
    }

    /**
     * Parses the push notification json
     *
     * @param context
     * @param json
     */
    private void parsePushJson(Context context, JSONObject json) {
        try {
            boolean isBackground = json.getBoolean("is_background");
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");

            if (!isBackground) {
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                showNotificationMessage(context, title, message, resultIntent);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Push message json exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }



    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, Intent intent) {

        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);

        intent.putExtras(parseIntent.getExtras());

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, intent);
    }
}
```

and my Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;

        // register with parse
        ParseUtils.registerParse(this);
    }


    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this problem. Please help Thanks in adavance

Comment: Have you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the application name to your manifest file?

And also check the following code in the manifest

```
<permission
    android:name="yourpackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="yourpackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="yourpackagename" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```